# Symfony 3 form type error

Tags: php, symfony

I have the entity "News" with fields:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $name;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $description;
```

I generate the form in my controller:

```
public function createNewsAction(Request $request)
{
    $news = new News();
    $news->setName('New!');
    $news->setDescription('test');
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($news)
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ->add('description', TextType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Task'))
        ->getForm();
    return $this->render('frontend/createNews.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

And when I try to call this method ("createNewsAction") I got the error:

```
Could not load type "Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType"

500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException

Stack Trace

in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php at line 87   -
                if (class_exists($name) && in_array('Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface', class_implements($name))) {
                    $type = new $name();
                } else {
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Could not load type "%s"', $name));
                }
            }
```

What I do wrong with this code?

Comment: TextType and SubmitType need a use statement.  Check the examples.

Comment: I find error. In controller instead statement "use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType;" must be "use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check your `use` statement at the top of your controller...
You've probably used:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TextType
```

It should be:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
```